Snakemake not re-running workflow or rule after script update
In snakemake, how do I indicate that a script is a dependency of an output file such that if the script changes, the rule will re-run?
For example, let's say this is my rule;
rule myrule:
    input:
        "foo.csv"
    output:
        "foobar.csv"
    script:
        "barfoo.py"

I assumed, wrongly I think, that if I change barfoo.py and do snakemake, that will trigger a re-run of the rule. However, that does not seem to be the case. After changes to barfoo.py and running snakemake, it says everything is up to date.
I'm new to snakemake, so I am be missing basic and fundamental. My apologies if so (I have searched and rtfm-ed). I assume there is some way to do this, like there is with GNU Make. e.g
foobar.csv: foo.csv foobar.py
    python foobar.py foo.csv foobar.csv

At present, I am doing a snakemake --foreceall after I change the script, but that seems to defeat the purpose.

with version 8.4.8, i can not reproduce your scenario. When I change barfoo.py snakemake will rerun and even tell me why:
Reasons:
    (check individual jobs above for details)
    code has changed since last execution:
        myrule

The command which regulates that behavior is --rerun-triggers, per default all triggers should be active, but you could try to play with it and see if it has an effect. E.g. --rerun-triggers code.
Which snakemake version are you running?

Thank you kEKs. I am using snakemake 8.20.1. I will test this with a small scale test to see if I can get this workflow to re-run after a script change. The actual workflow that I am using takes around 1hr to complete, even in parallel, which makes experimenting more difficult.

This is the correct answer in that my original question was based on a mistaken understanding. While it is true that my workflow (hour long ish in total) was not re-running after a script change, the reason for this must be something peculiar to what I was doing rather than a general feature of snakemake. When I tried to reproduce the problem on a much smaller scale, I did not experience it. In other words, the workflow would re-run on a script change.
